# How to find the volume of the solid enclosed between a $\Bbb B_{r}^{n-1}$ and $\Bbb S^{n}_{R}$

Tags: calculus, geometry, euclidean-geometry, spheres

How to find the volume of the solid enclosed between the ball $\Bbb B^{n-1}_{r}$ and $\Bbb S^{n}_{R}$ such that $r<2R$?

For example in case $n=3$ the volume of the solid enclosed between a sphere of radius $R$ and a 2-ball (disk) of radius $r<2R$ inside of sphere.
 (as shown in below)
[image]

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you make a drawing?

Comment: Edited your question to call the smaller dimensioned object "ball" instead of "sphere"